# Filling in missing values in one dataset based on another in presence of repeated observations in R

Tags: dataset

Using R, I would like to use information from dataframe 2 to fill in missing values in dataframe 1. Here are the headers from my files. File 1 is a dataframe with data and location (long/lat) of an event. Some of the spatial information is missing.

```
> head(file1)
  day.of.event longitude latitude  PLZ    
1   01.01.2009    750303   243535 9050 
2   01.01.2009    645616   235136 5056  
3   01.01.2009    722132   253715 9602 
4   01.01.2009    645149   222845 8836    
5   01.01.2009        NA       NA 3000      
6   01.01.2009        NA       NA 3000
```

However, based on the postcode (PLZ) , I can find these in the Swiss official register (cadastre). The NAs in the first file should be replaced by the E/N corresponding to the PLZ (postcode).

```
> head(file2)
  Ortschaftsname  PLZ Zusatzziffer Gemeindename Kantonskürzel      E      N
1         Aadorf 8355            0       Aadorf            TG 710450 261277
2          Aarau 5000            0        Aarau            AG 646063 248867
3          Aarau 5004            0        Aarau            AG 646950 250197
4     Aarau Rohr 5032            0        Aarau            AG 648491 250615
5        Aarberg 3270            0      Aarberg            BE 588188 210368
6        Aarburg 4663            0      Aarburg            AG 635148 241461
```

Now as I have several hundreds of thousands of events, the postcode will be repeated but I would like to replace all NAs for postcode "3000"(for example) with the same longitude (E) and latitude (N)(repeat for all NAs).

There must be an easier way than doing this manually?

Comment: Apart from this being arguably off-topic, it is poor practice in any forum not dedicated to specific software not to state the software being used.

Comment: Yes Nick, you are right, i have edited my post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the following is not the best way to do this task, but if the order doesnot matter than you could do something like this.

a<-subset(file1,PLZ==3000) # extract all the rows where PLZ is 3000

b<-subset(file1,PLZ!=3000) # remaining part of dataframe

a$longitude<-rep(lonvalue,nrow(a))

a$latitude<-rep(latvalue,nrow(a))

file1<-rbind(b,a)

in the above code, either hardcode or pass by variable the value of latitude or longitude you want to add

EDIT:

You can write a loop. Iterate over all rows of file1

something like:

```
for row in row.numbers

{

if is.na(file1$longitude[row])

{ 
t=subset(file2,PLZ==file1$PLZ[row])

  file1$longitude[row]<-t$E

  file1$latitude[row]<-t$N

}

}
```

the above will work if in file2 for each PLZ there is a single row

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I realise I wasn't clear enough. I only provided the PLZ"3000" as an example. I would like to replace the NAs for all corresponding PLZ.

Comment: You can write a loop. Iterate over all rows of file1

Comment: i have added the code as an edit in the answer above